Issue with Maven build - com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap NoClassDefFound
I'm a bit of a Java noob, and running into issues when following instructions for a git repo requiring a Maven build:
https://github.com/Salesforce-Async-Messaging/key-command-line-utility
And after installing Maven clean install, following instructions, ran into an isse:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
After checking other issues similar, the issue seems to be Maven not able to access or by pathclass, the guava dependency for collect.ImmutableMap. I did see the Guava .jar file in Maven, but when I went to download Guava for that repo, and unzipping, I can see collect.ImmutableMap in the download among the other .java files, but not completely sure how and where I go about adding to installing as to a location that Maven can locate.
I've seen some answers to this regarding adding dependency, etc, but where would I add that? Any help for a java noob, I would appreciate it.
Ive followed all instructions from:
https://github.com/Salesforce-Async-Messaging/key-command-line-utility
And on error during running the java command line, I've downloaded the zip file from
https://github.com/google/guava
But not sure as to what to do with the loose .java files, or where exactly to put a dependency/path entry for Maven to find the class. Java 22.0.2, Windows

You should not add that dependency manually if it is available in the Maven Central repository. The problem is that there is a version conflict somewhere.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
